# Predicate generic method

Tags: java, generics

I wrote a `Predicate` code that takes any `Object` and tests it for the following conditions:

1. if `Object` type is `String` and contains `"k"` then it should return true.
2. if `Object` type is `Integer` and greater than `100` then it should return true.
3. if `Object` type is `Employee` which is class and having salary of employee greater than `60000`, it should return true.

After writing that `Predicate` method I wrote the `remove` method that removes values from list according to `Predicate` method.

```
public class ConditionalRemove {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("ramesh", "kushal", "suresh", "kc"));
        System.out.println(conditionalRemove(list));
    }

    public static <T> List<T> conditionalRemove(ArrayList<T> list) {
        ConditionCheck<T> cond = new ConditionCheck<>();
        for (T t : list) {
            if (cond.test(t)) {
                list.remove(t);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    static class ConditionCheck<T> implements Predicate<T> {
        @Override
        public boolean test(T t) {
            if (t instanceof String) {
                return (((String) t).contains("k"));
            } else if (t instanceof Integer) {
                return ((int) t > 100);
            } else if (t instanceof Employee) {
                return ((int) ((Employee) t).getSalary() < 60000);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

After compiling this code I found `Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: You are deleting from the list while you are iterating it (in `conditionalRemove()`. To fix, make a copy of the list and iterate that.

Comment: @nbokmans - Not necessary - just use Iterator explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are updating the list when you are iterating over that. The issue can be fixed by updating code as

```
public static <T> List<T> conditionalRemove(ArrayList<T> list) {
        ConditionCheck<T> cond = new ConditionCheck<>();
        Iterator it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())     
        {
            it.next();
            if (cond.test(t)) {
                it.remove();
            }
         }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: instead of `it.remove(t)` i wrote `it.remove()` that work for me.

Comment: Variable `t` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Java 8, a functional approach would be to create a new filtered list:

```
public static <T> List<T> conditionalRemove(ArrayList<T> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(new ConditionCheck<>())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can even replace the static inner class by just a method:

```
public static <T> List<T> conditionalRemove(ArrayList<T> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(ConditionalRemove::test)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static <T> boolean test(T t) {
    // your predicate implementation...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel: Use [`Collection#removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
public static <T> List<T> conditionalRemove(ArrayList<T> list) {
    list.removeIf(new ConditionCheck<>());
    return list;
}
```

At one line, this is hardly worth the effort of creating a method to call... just make the single line call in-line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ramesh", "kushal", "suresh", "kc"));
    list.removeIf(new ConditionCheck<>());
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some data structures throws the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when you modify them during an iteration, in order to do that with success you need use a synchronized structure such as "[CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)", this is the java doc reference

Hope this can help you!

Regards.